# Can squid add X-Forworded-For header in https request?

Tags: squid, x-forwarded-for

I know squid can perform as a mitm,so I want to know can squid add X-Forworded-For header in https request?
If can add, how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

I Dont think so it can be done currently there are following options only

- If set to "on", Squid will append your client's IP address
  in the HTTP requests it forwards. By default it looks like: `X-Forwarded-For: 192.1.2.3`
- If set to "off", it will appear as `X-Forwarded-For: unknown`
- If set to "transparent", Squid will not alter the X-Forwarded-For header in any way.
- If set to "delete", Squid will delete the entire X-Forwarded-For header.
- If set to "truncate", Squid will remove all existing X-Forwarded-For entries, and place the client IP as the sole entry